# Run maven-based android project in eclipse with apklib-dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

i have a maven-based android project which uses the ActionbarSherlock as an apklib-dependency and Gson as an jar-dependency. Building the application with maven works just fine, but i cant start/run the application using eclipse as long as the ActionbarSherlock dependency is added.

Is it possible that eclipse can´t handle the apklib-dependency? I also had to add the lib as a library project to my eclipse workspace and add the dependency to maven. otherwise i can´t access the actionbarsherlock from my code...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for apklib dependencies in ADT Eclipse is part of ongoing work for the [m2e-android](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) project. Please comment on this issue to stay updated:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

The current workaround is to add the complete source code of apklib to your workspace.